# Backbone.js fires render twice on collection add

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working with the Todos example application [bundled with the latest version of Backbone](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/) (0.9.2) while learning about Backbone.js. My question is, why is the app designed to fire the render event twice when adding a model to the Todos collection?

If I place this line within the TodoView's render function:

```
// Re-render the titles of the todo item.
render: function() {
  console.log("Rendering!");
  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

Then "Rendering!" appears twice in the console. I understand this is because the view binds the model's change event to the view's render:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
```

And render is called in addOne, which is bound to the Todos' add event:

```
addOne: function(todo) {
  var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
  this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
},
```

But is this double rendering design standard practice? It seems like the view should be rendered on creation (or entrance into the DOM), and then again if the underlying model changes. In this case, nothing is being changed, but render is being called twice.

Again, I am just learning Backbone, so I may have a basic misunderstanding that is leading to my confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, had a quick look. You are right that this happens, and no it's not standard practice.
The reason is a bit obscure, so bear with me ;)

The todo app is using backbone-localstorage. When you try adding a new item in the app it calls:

```
createOnEnter: function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
  if (!this.input.val()) return;

  Todos.create({title: this.input.val()});
  this.input.val('');
},
```

Notice the `Todos.create`. Normally a `create` will add a model to the collection as well as save it on the server. The `add` event will thus be triggered. It happens though that backbone-localstorage does the following on `create`:

```
create: function(model) {
  if (!model.id) model.set(model.idAttribute, guid());
  this.data[model.id] = model;
  this.save();
  return model;
},
```

Notice the `model.set` to give the model an id. This is what triggers the (second) `change` event.

You can stop this from happening by changing create to do:

`if (!model.id) model.id = guid();`

Comment: nice catch!.. you also can use `{silent: true}` to avoid events triggering.

Comment: You are right, that is the reason the change event is being fired. However, changing the code in the way you suggested stops the event but also breaks functionality (I can no longer delete items). Obviously this doesn't matter much in terms of answering my question, but just in case someone in the future reads this, I wanted to point that out.

Comment: Delete items _permanently_ that is. After deleting, if I refresh they still exist.

Comment: Deletimg can not be affected unless you changed other things too or there is another bug. I guess the backbone-localstorage might need a good clean up some time soon;)

Answer (score 1):

The *re-render* shouldn't happen.

Try to *debug* a little more. Try to bind the *change* event to a *wrapper method* like:

```
initialize: function(){
  this.model.bind( "change", this.renderWrapper, this );
}, 

renderWrapper: function(){
  console.log( "in the renderWrapper" );
  this.render();
}
```

To be sure the second `render()` was made for the *change event bind* and not for other reason.

Comment: You are right. I should have noted in my question that I originally narrowed this down by putting `console.log('Change!')` in place of the `this.render()`. Hence I was sure the change event was firing.