# Backbone.js Binding to collection "add" renders view twice

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to trace all of the zombies in my application and get better understanding of how the event binding happens.
I have a view that binds its collection `"add"` event to its `render` function.

```
_.bindAll(this, "render");
this.collection.bind("add", this.render);
```

So if I log something in my render function I can see in console that rendering happened twice right after user adds new model through UI. The console output looks like this:

```
rendering                                  index.js?body=1 (line 88)

POST http://localhost:3000/tasks           jquery.js?body=1 (line 8103)

rendering                                  index.js?body=1 (line 88)
```

I wonder why is this happening. I know for a fact that model was added only once to the collection so that makes me think that event should only be fired once. Then I don't understand why `render` was executed twice.
I have looked in similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228267/backbone-js-fires-render-twice-on-collection-add) but it is different because I am using `add` event instead of `change`.

Comment: You should show us more code. What is the code that implement this _"user adds new model through UI"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was an additional binding to `render` through Event Aggregator. It was added by another developer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you instantiate your view twice? It might be 2 different views.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are calling render two times.

Yoy are doing something like this:

```
var yourView = new YourDefinedView();
yourView.render(); // this is your manual call to render

//here you call to the server and when data arrives is the second render
this.collection.fetch();
```

I do not think that render is the best method to bind when a collection receives a new item.

Check this example how we bind a specific event for add items from the Collection to the View:
http://danielarandaochoa.com/backboneexamples/blog/2012/02/22/real-world-usage-of-a-backbone-collection/